# How to make multiple mySQL database update from PHP form with one form submit?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm struggling with this issue:
I have this function in my `functions.php` file

```
function list_cart()
{   
    global $con;
    $ip = take_ip();
    $query = "select * from cart where ip_adr='$ip'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if($count==0)
        {
            echo "<h2>No items in shopping cart!</h2>";
        }
    while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
        {
            $id = $rows["art_id"];
            $total = $rows["total"];
            $qty = $rows["qty"];
        echo"    
             <h3>Quantity: <input type='text' name='quantity' size='1' value='$qty' />
             Price: $total € <input type='checkbox' name='remove[]' value='$id'/></h3>";
        }         
}
```

Then I call that function in my `cart_content.php` file, together with some code that prints the list of items, with their quantities in a textbox, total price and a checkbox for selecting items for deletion (all data is in a mySQL table). It works like it should. What I'd like to add is if I manually change quantities in those boxes and press on the "Update cart" button that those items marked for deletion get deleted and those with changed quantities get the new quantities written in the mySQL table. The rest of the code is here:

```
 <?php if(isset($_POST["update"]))

                $ip = take_ip ();

                foreach ($_POST["remove"] as $remove_id) 
                {
                    $query = "delete from cart where art_id='$remove_id' and ip_adr='$ip'";
                    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);                  
                }
if($result)
{
    header("Location: cart_content.php");
}
```

I have tried several things that I've found on the net but got utterly lost in the process. I'd appreciate some help. And for those wondering, no, this is not production code, just something I'm trying to make.

Comment: If i got it right...you can do exactly like you did for the remove..in the update part just update the quantities...

Comment: My advise is to keep your cart in the session. IP address can be shared if 2 or more customers are behind NAT. If your customer is logged I would save his/her cart in the serialized variable linked to account id.
How to update quantities? Each row in your cart should have its own id linked to the hidden field by field name, then when your customer press submit you should read POST and analyze it compared to your cart stored in the session and update the cart accordingly and then if user is logged save the cart as serialized variable to the database

Comment: Just added some code snapshots slightly different to my comment above, but  general idea is the same. You need to send some data in POST, if name of your input box is defined as product[id] you can simply read POST variables sent after user pressed submit button. From my own experience ... writing your own shopping cart solution is pretty complex and time consuming. I would advice not to do it unless you have very good reason to do so. Why not just use existing system, at least as a reference. Just analyze the code of e.g. opencart. IMHO it is pretty well written.

Answer (score 0):

Just write your program to do the update and delete functions you need, one after the other. This is a very common sort of thing to do.

You can get into trouble if you do a Select operation in the midst of your other operations, and don't read the entire result set first.

Also, if you happen to get false $result values from queries, that means you had an error. You need to use mysqli_error in that case to see what the error was.

Answer (score 0):

Life example,

HTML:

```
  <form id="cartProducts" method="post" action="../../../catalog/modules/cart/?ccsForm=CartProducts" autocomplete="off">

    <div class="Caption">
        <div class="name">Produkt</div>
        <div class="quantity">Ilość</div>
        <div class="price_unit">Cena</div>
        <div class="remove">Usuń</div>
    </div>

    <table width="100%" class="cart">

        <tr>

            <td class="image"><img src="../../../catalog/gfx/A/1140855796_83551.png" >&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="product"><a href="../../../catalog/modules/product/?p=1140855796{}{26}">ACTIVLAB 6 Protein Blend 2000g</a><span class="packet"><br>Smak: wiśnia</span>&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="quantity">

                <a class="minus" href="#"></a>
                <input class="qty" name="qty[1140855796{}{26}]" value="2">
                <a class="plus" href="#"></a>

            </td>
            <td class="price_unit">139,98 zł&nbsp;</td>
            <td ><a href="../../../catalog/modules/cart/?a=delete&p=1140855796{}{26}"><span class="delete_icon"></span></a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="separator">
            <td colspan="5"></td>
        </tr>


        <tr class="Buttons">
            <td colspan="5" >
 ....
</form>
```

PHP snapshots:

```
$cart = clsCart::getInstance();
/* @var $cart clsCart */
if (is_array($_POST['qty'])) {
    foreach ($_POST['qty'] as $key => $value) {
    $cart->UpdateQuantity($key, $value);
    }
}
```

...

```
/**
 * updates cart quantity
 * @param type $product_key
 * @param type $new_qty 
 */
public function UpdateQuantity($product_key, $new_qty) {
    $this->_Products[$product_key]['quantity'] = 0;
    $this->AddProduct($new_qty, $product_key);
    $this->Recalculate();
}
```